# Saving and loading an object in java that isn't a string or int

Tags: java, javafx, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to save and load an object in my java application which is an extension of another class.

I can currently save and load the current class but i want to be able to save the specific object as you can see in the code below i have declared my class Building and called it theBuilding, i want to save and load this. What is currently happening is its saving and loading the BuildingGUI rather than the specific object

```
public class BuildingGUI extends Application implements Serializable{

private Building theBuilding;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BuildingGUI Building2 = new BuildingGUI();
    try
      {
         //Create file output stream
         FileOutputStream fileOutStr =  new 
FileOutputStream("theBuilding.ser"); 
        //Create object output stream and write object
         ObjectOutputStream objOutStr = new 
ObjectOutputStream(fileOutStr);
         objOutStr.writeObject(Building2);
         //Close all streams
         objOutStr.close();
         fileOutStr.close();
         System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in a file  - 
 theBuilding.ser");
      }catch(IOException exp)
      {
          System.out.println("Error IOException");
          exp.printStackTrace();
      }


BuildingGUI Building = null;{
try
  {
     FileInputStream fileInStr = new FileInputStream("theBuilding.ser");
     ObjectInputStream objInStr = new ObjectInputStream(fileInStr);
     Building = (BuildingGUI) objInStr.readObject();
     objInStr.close();
     fileInStr.close();
  }catch(IOException exp)
  {
      System.out.println("Error IOException");
     exp.printStackTrace();
     return;
  }catch(ClassNotFoundException cexp)
  {
     System.out.println("BuildingGUI class not found");
     cexp.printStackTrace();
     return;
  }
System.out.println(", theBuilding has been deserialized");
```

The code above does what its supposed to by saving the BuildingGUI class file then loading it again but i want it to save a specific object which is private Building theBuilding;

Thank you for any help

Comment: Move the logic from your `main(String[] args)`, to a method that takes a `Building()` as an argument. Then you can save that specific instance and load it as needed.

Comment: @KleoG yes, you can see that from the post

Comment: I've added an extensively thorough explanation of how you can achieve what you want. You can copy/paste the code in your IDE/Text Editor to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you claim that your code is working, I just copied it and pasted it from your original question.

You were on the right path, you just:

1. Need a method, that when invoked from your main, will take a BuildingGUI as the argument and serialize it to be stored on disk.
2. Need a method, that when invoked, will take the file name as the argument, de-serialize the file and give you a BuildingGUI back.

**You can do the exact same thing, but for `Building` type objects. Just change the parameters of the method to accept `Building`, instead of `BuildingGUI`.**

---

```
    //Method to serialize and store specific BuildingGUI
    public void buildingSaver(BuildingGUI building) throws IOException {
        //Create file output stream
        FileOutputStream fileOutStr = new FileOutputStream("theBuilding.ser");
        //Create object output stream and write object
        ObjectOutputStream objOutStr = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutStr);
        objOutStr.writeObject(Building2);
        //Close all streams
        objOutStr.close();
        fileOutStr.close();
        System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in a file  - theBuilding.ser");
    }

    //Method to deserialize BuildingGUI from file
    public BuildingGUI buildingLoader(String filename) throws IOException,
                                                    ClassNotFoundException{
        FileInputStream fileInStr = new FileInputStream(filename);
        ObjectInputStream objInStr = new ObjectInputStream(fileInStr);
        BuildingGUI building = (BuildingGUI) objInStr.readObject();
        objInStr.close();
        fileInStr.close();

        return building;
    }
```

- > What happens if you have many types of object that you'll need to
  >   store?
- > Do you need to write a separate method for all of them?

The answer is **no**.

You could have a more generic (and also `static`) method that accepts an object as a parameter, like so:

```
    //parameter is Object, instead of Building
    public static void writeObjectToDisk(Object obj, String name) throws IOException {
        //Create file output stream
        FileOutputStream fileOutStr = new FileOutputStream(name);
        //Create object output stream and write object
        ObjectOutputStream objOutStr = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutStr);
        objOutStr.writeObject(obj);
        //Close all streams
        objOutStr.close();
        fileOutStr.close();
        System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in a file  - "+name);
    }

    public static Object objectLoader(String filename) throws IOException,
                                                      ClassNotFoundException{
        FileInputStream fileInStr = new FileInputStream(filename);
        ObjectInputStream objInStr = new ObjectInputStream(fileInStr);
        Object obj = (Object) objInStr.readObject();
        objInStr.close();
        fileInStr.close();

        return obj;
    }
```

To get a `Building` from inside `BuildingGUI`, you will need an accessor method:

```
public class BuildingGUI extends Application implements Serializable{

    private Building theBuilding;

    public Building getBuilding(){
        return this.theBuilding;
    }

    /*other code..*/
}
```

Finally, inside your `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //initialize BuildingGUI object and get the Building object
    BuildingGUI building2 = new BuildingGUI();
    Building myBuilding = building2.getBuilding();

    //we serialize the Building, by casting it to (Object) and feeding it to the method
    try{
        someClass.writeObjectToDisk((Object)myBuilding);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    Building myBuilding2 = null;
    BuildingGUI buildingGUI = null;
    //now for deserializing
    try{
        //We cast to appropriate type, because method returns 'Object'
        myBuilding2 = (Building)objectLoader("building.ser");
        buildingGUI = (BuildingGUI)objectLoader("buildingGUI.ser");
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Final Note**:
If you initialize the `Building` object reference, inside your `BuildingGUI` class. Then when you serialize `BuildingGUI`, you implicitly serialize the `Building` object reference as well. So, when you **de-serialize** `BuildingGUI`, you'll be able to access `Building` as well. I will add one final paradigm.

```
public class BuildingGUI extends Application implements Serializable{

    private Building theBuilding = new Building(); <-- we initialize it

    public Building getBuilding(){
        return this.theBuilding;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //initialize BuildingGUI object and get the Building object
    BuildingGUI building2 = new BuildingGUI();

    //we serialize the Building, by casting it to (Object) and feeding it to the method
    try{
        someClass.writeObjectToDisk((Object)building2);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    BuildingGUI buildingGUI = null;
    //now for deserializing JUST THE BUILDINGGUI
    try{
        //We cast to appropriate type, because method returns 'Object'
        buildingGUI = (BuildingGUI)ObjectLoader("buildingGUI.ser");
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
    }

    //You can get the building this way
    Building myBuilding = buildingGUI.getBuilding();
}
```

Comment: Is that still dealing with the BuildingGUI? as i want it to deal with the object Building theBuilding;

Comment: @CurtisB see the updated answer. Any object you need to store on disk, must be `Serializable`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

In your `main()` method, you have a local variable named `Building2` which is an instance of class `BuildingGUI`:

```
BuildingGUI Building2 = new BuildingGUI();
```

A few lines later, you are writing that object to a file:

```
objOutStr.writeObject(Building2);
```

So, that's why your program is writing a `BuildingGUI` object to the file.

Your class `BuildingGUI` has a member variable named `theBuilding` of type `Building` declared. If you just want to write that `Building` object to the file, then you have to change the line that writes the object to just write that object:

```
// Write the Building object that is contained
// in the BuildingGUI object to the file
objOutStr.writeObject(Building2.theBuilding);
```

However, something else is missing: you are not initializing the member variable `theBuilding` anywhere in your code, so it will be set to the default value `null`. You'll need to properly initialize it, for example by changing line 3 to this:

```
private Building theBuilding = new Building();
```

Note, this is just an example, you didn't show us class `Building` so I don't know if it has a constructor that takes no arguments which allows you to instantiate it like this, or if you need to pass parameters to the constructor or instantiate the object another way.

You'll also have to change the code that loads the data from the file, because you want to load a `Building` object there and not a `BuildingGUI` object.

Comment: Hi so would i just need to change those few lines in order for it to just write and load the building object? I am happy to show class building but didn't want to put loads of irrelevant code as there is alot more in my gui class as well but just tried to take the necessary code out

Comment: @CurtisB I'm giving you pointers to look at in your code - don't just copy my suggestions without thinking about it. The points to look at are: pass the correct object to `writeObject()`, make sure the `Building` object is initialized, change the code that loads the object to load a `Building` object instead of a `BuildingGUI` object.

Comment: @CurtisB Also, please consider moving all that code (for serialization and deserialization) from `main` method, to **two** distinct methods, like I explain in my answer. This will make these methods reusable throughout other classes as well. It's the whole point of having an *Object-Oriented Language*, like Java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question well, but I'll give it a try.
First question : Is the `Building` class `Serializable` ?

If so, it's a good start. Then what you are doing right now is calling a Serialize code from a static context (in the main method) and you are doing :

```
objOutStr.writeObject(Building2);
```

So effectively, the object `BuildingGUI` is serialized as expected.
If you want to Serialize the `Building` object, you need an access to it, by means of a getter for example :

```
public Building getBuilding() {
  return theBuilding;
}
```

Then replace in your code by : `objOutStr.writeObject(Building2.getBuilding());`

Then when Deserialization takes place, you'll have a Building class Object.

Comment: hi yes all my classes are serializable

Answer (score -1):

You can use : Jackson. It's a mapper, it can transform an object into a json format. Then, you will be able to load this json string into the specific given Object